# For loop including "if" and "while" running for hours

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, simulation

I have a for loop including “if” and “while” clauses written for a question. It is intended to do 1000 simulations with some conditions. I think it is not a very complicated loop, but it has been running for almost 16 hours without showing a result or prompting an error/warning (and the little red stop sign has been shown all this time),  and I can feel that my laptop has been slowed down since I started running the loop.

So I wonder if this is something that could actually happen, or if there’s anything wrong with my code or my laptop. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Please see below for the code:

```
result.Vec <- NULL
for (trials in 1:1000) {
  sum <- 0
  sum2 <- 0
  n <- 0
  tmp1 <- sample(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), size=1, replace=T, prob=c(1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6)) 
  tmp2 <- sample(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), size=1, replace=T, prob=c(1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6)) 
  sum <- tmp1 + tmp2
  if (sum == 7 || sum == 11) {
    n <- 1
   } else if (sum == 2 || sum == 3 || sum == 12) {
    n <- 0
   } else {
     while (sum2 != sum || sum2 != 7) {
       tmp1 <- sample(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), size=1, replace=T, prob=c(1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6)) 
       tmp2 <- sample(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), size=1, replace=T, prob=c(1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6)) 
       sum2 <- tmp1 + tmp2
       if (sum2 == sum) {
         n <- 1
       } else if (sum2 == 7) {
         n <- 0
       }
     }
   }
  result.Vec <- c(result.Vec, n)
}
```

Please see below for the question that my loop is for as a reference (not seeking a solution to this problem): 
The dice game craps is played as follows. The player throws two dice, and if the sum is seven or eleven, then she wins. If the sum is two, three, or twelve, then she loses. If the sum is anything else, then she continues throwing until she either throws that number again (in which case she wins) or she throws a seven (in which case she loses). Calculate the probability that the player wins based on 1000 simulations.

Comment: Probably your `while()` is stuck, since the condition to exit never evaluates to false. You should make a `counter` to limit this possibility, update the `counter` at each while iteration, then use `if()` and `break` to exit early.

Comment: You should update your question maybe explaining what you're trying to simulate, seems like some sort of dice draws..

Comment: @RLave Thanks for your response! Below the code block I think I included the body of the question that I’m trying to solve. Can you not see it?

Comment: Your code is fine, but the condition in the while should be & instead of |, because otherwise the condition is always false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the problem just sits with the condition in the while loop. It should be AND instead of OR, or the while loop will always fail. I've tested this and it works:

```
result.Vec <- NULL
for (trials in 1:1000) {
  print(trials)
  sum <- 0
  sum2 <- 0
  n <- 0
  tmp1 <- sample(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), size=1, replace=T, prob=c(1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6)) 
  tmp2 <- sample(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), size=1, replace=T, prob=c(1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6)) 
  sum <- tmp1 + tmp2
  if (sum == 7 | sum == 11) {
    n <- 1
  } else if (sum == 2 | sum == 3 | sum == 12) {
    n <- 0
  } else {
    while (sum2 != sum & sum2 != 7) {
      tmp1 <- sample(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), size=1, replace=T, prob=c(1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6)) 
      tmp2 <- sample(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), size=1, replace=T, prob=c(1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6)) 
      sum2 <- tmp1 + tmp2
      if (sum2 == sum) {
        n <- 1
      } else if (sum2 == 7) {
        n <- 0
      }
    }
  }
  result.Vec <- c(result.Vec, n)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first, in order to speed up the code you should get rid of the outer for loop. Instead use a function which simulates one game and then use `replicate` to run the game `n` times.

Secondly, use `break` to exit the while loop. Also, note that it is not wise to name a variable `sum` since there is already an R function named `sum`.

Here is my version of your code:

```
simulate_game <- function(){

  tmp1 <- sample(x = 1:6, size = 1) 
  tmp2 <- sample(x = 1:6, size = 1) 

  mysum <- tmp1 + tmp2

  if (mysum %in% c(7, 11)) {
    n <- 1
  } else if (mysum  %in% c(2, 3, 12)) {
    n <- 0
  } else {
    mysum2 <- 0

    while (! mysum2 %in% c(mysum, 7)) {
      tmp1 <- sample(x = 1:6, size = 1) 
      tmp2 <- sample(x = 1:6, size = 1) 

      mysum2 <- tmp1 + tmp2

      if (mysum2 == mysum) {
        n <- 1; break()
      } else if (mysum2 == 7) {
        n <- 0; break()
      }
    }
  }

  return(n)
}
```

Now you can use the following to simulate 1000 runs:

```
set.seed(1)
table(replicate(1000, simulate_game()))
      0   1 
     530 470
```

Note that I set a random seed using `set.seed`. This makes your results reproducible.

Comment: It's not? I didn't know. Anyway I find code easier to read when replicate is used instead of a for loop.

Comment: Just checked, in this case, it is faster. Sometimes it's not, like `lapply`. Anyway I agree with you, it is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop get stuck:

```
while (sum2 != sum || sum2 != 7)
```

If sum != 7 ( so for almost any possible value) this will always evaluate to TRUE.